# CSS isn't working in any browser unless I use inline styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, inline-styles

I have this problem with any div id or when trying to select an element within a class (CSS example: .className li{} ), so I can only assume that I’m doing something wrong. The inline styles work, but if I try to add them to my stylesheet, they won’t show up.

I can see the CSS styles in mobile view, but it’s not working in any browser on my computer.

I’m pretty sure my CSS files are linked properly because the navigation menu is working fine… However, my .js file isn’t working for the page content or the footer. Basically, the header is the only thing that is fully functional and styled.

Example:

Trying to change the background color of the footer:

HTML:

```
<div id=“footer”>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <p>TEXT HERE</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#footer {
    background-color: black;
}
```

If I do this in HTML it will work:

```
<div id="footer" style="background-color: black;">
```

Comment: Your style rule is just fine. If that rule is present in a correctly-loaded stylesheet, the browser **will** apply it. Here's how you correctly link an external stylesheet (somewhere in `head`): `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/stylesheet.css">` Look in your web console for errors, it sounds like the CSS isn't getting linked correctly.

Comment: If it's not a problem with linking, please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Verify that your HTML is valid (http://validator.w3.org) and your CSS is valid as well (https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)

Comment: I ran both validators, but the only errors that are coming up are with the bootstrap.css: "Property -moz-box-sizing is an unknown vendor extension"

Comment: "if I try to add them to my stylesheet, they won’t show up" almost certainly means you haven't linked the stylesheet correctly. Did you check the path, as TJ Crowder suggested?

Comment: I double checked the file path, and it's correct. The styles are showing up in mobile view, just not on any of the browsers or tablet landscape view.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `““` formatted quotes which is wrong. Please use double quotes `""` around ID like this

```
<div id="footer">
```

```css
#footer {
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <p>TEXT HERE</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what an answer that was posted well before yours was says. Please only add answers that add value to the issue.

Comment: Ok thank you for informing me . :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your development environment looks like, but if you're working on a live site, you might want to double check that your browser caching isn't loading a non-updated version of the CSS to the browser - Either through htaccess or through your hosting accounts admin area (cPanel, etc).

The obvious quick check for this is to clear your browser cache and see if the updates you've made are rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say that it is only the `footer` section of the page that you are having a problem with and if your actual code is what you've shown here, then the issue is likely that you are using formatted (smart) quotes around the `id="footer"` instead of unformatted (straight) quotes:

```
<div id=“footer”>
```

Also, make sure that you have saved your file with a standard character encoding (UTF-8 is most common) and add the following tag to your `head` section to declare that encoding to the user agent:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

You can read up on character encoding [**here**](https://www.sitepoint.com/guide-web-character-encoding/).

Comment: The quotes are unformatted in the actual document. I don't know why it showed up as formatted here.

Comment: @whatishappening Double check (and even retype them to be sure) and perform the saving and declaring of your character encoding as I've described and validate your HTML and CSS using the links I provided in the comments above. If the problem is truly isolated to the `footer`, you can be sure it's not a CSS issue, but something else.